# Windows 10 Mouse not responding after sleep

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse, sleep

I recently bought a new Windows 10 box which is a laptop. For whatever reason, when my laptop goes to sleep and then I wake it back up, my external USB mouse no longer works and the only way for me to navigate is either to use the trackpad OR unplug the mouse and plug it back in... The latter is a pain because the USB already fits kind of snug and it creates unnecessary wear on the port.

Things I've tried:

Went to Control Panel - Edit Power Plan -> Advanced -> USB -> Disabled "selective suspend" for USB ports... Problem still persists.
I also made sure that the setting for "allow pointing device to wake computer" was enabled and it was.

The thing that's bizarre is that the computer actually does recognize the fact that the mouse is still plugged in when it wakes up because when I checked the option to "disable the trackpad when external pointing device is connected", the trackpad immediately became disabled, even when the mouse wasn't working due to the computer having just woken up. Also, the USB driver recognizes the fact that it's plugged in...

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

So no idea why this is happening. For me, it began happening after the most recent windows update (as of 2/18/2019), and right after my computer goes to sleep as well. I've noticed that you can go to mouse settings -> additional mouse options -> hardware -> (specific device) -> properties (change settings) -> driver, rollback the driver, then re-update the driver right after. It's definitely annoying, but I've noticed that I'm having this issue less often (rather than every single time) now. And for me, it beats having to restart in the case that I have many/important windows open. Good luck though, would love to hear of a proper fix.